Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) token refresh endpoint returning 404 Not Found
ORDS version: 22.4
Database version: Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0
Database schema: apitest
I am trying to refresh the Oauth2 bearer token via the API endpoint but it returns a 404.
I'm using Postman as follows:
Endpoint (masked URL!): POST https://something.something.com:8080/ords/apitest/oauth2/token
I've included the client id and client secret in the username and password fields under the authorisation tab (auth type = basic auth). In the Body I've used x-www-form-urlencoded, and added grant_type with a value of client_credentials.
I have used the exact same setup on my personal OCI account with Postman and it all works fine. Replicating on an on-prem system at work, and it returns a 404.
I have successfully hosted APIs and they all work fine via Postman. I can manually retrieve the bearer token from Database Actions dashboard and again, all works fine. It's just the token refresh via the API endpoint that returns a 404.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

here I have /oauth/token not /oauth2/token

Thanks. Just tried it with oauth and same response - 404 :(

if apitest is the domain of you own handlers, not sure it should be there:
here /ords/application/api/xyz and /ords/application/oauth/token, if you don't have the application level then try /ords/oauth/token (or oauth2)

apitest is the schema. Good idea. I tried knocking out various parts of the url, and changing oauth2 to oauth. same result.
